# python 3.7 pygame error "not responding" use to work

Tags: python, pygame

i am trying to make a moving spaceship in python but i get an error that says "not responding"
i have loaded code in pygame before but now it wont work and i dont know why here is the code

```
import pygame

 def player(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerImg, (x, y))

    pygame.init()

 screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
 playerImg = pygame.image.load("spaceship.png")

    for event in pygame.event.get():
     if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
              
playerX = 350
playerY = 500
playerX_change = 0

playerX -= 2

running = True;
while running:
   screen.fill((255, 0, 0))
player(playerX, playerY)

playerX -= 1
pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the **full text** of your error. You also have inconsistent indentation, which could be effecting things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix you main loop to listen for system events.

Try this code:

```
running = True;
while running:
   for events in pygame.event.get(): #get all pygame events
        if events.type == pygame.QUIT: #if event is quit then shutdown window and program
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

   screen.fill((255, 0, 0))
   player(playerX, playerY)

   playerX -= 1
   pygame.display.update()
```